# How can i put a progress cursor when Submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, forms

How can i add to my code a progress cursor to inform the user to wait when he clicks the Submit button or the Upload Button when uploads many files?
Here is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="*">
        <input type="submit" value="Ανέβασμα Αρχείων">


    </form>

    <form action="execute.php" method="post" >
        <input type="submit" value="Εκτέλεση ελέγχου">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load Progress Cursor on click of submit button as below.

```
<div id="progressMessage" style="display:none; padding:5px; border:1px Solid #000">
        <div id="activityIndicator">&nbsp;</div>
        <label style="font:bold; display:block; padding:5px; text-align: centre;"
             id="progressMessageLbl">Loading...</label>
    </div>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="*">
    <input type="submit" value="Ανέβασμα Αρχείων" onclick="showProgressCursor();">
</form>

<form action="execute.php" method="post" >
    <input type="submit" value="Εκτέλεση ελέγχου" onclick="showProgressCursor();">

</form>
```

JavaScript Code

```
function showProgressCursor()
{
   $("#progressMessageLbl").html("Loading....");
   $("#progressMessage").show();
}
```

CSS

```
 #progressMessage
 {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    left:25%;
    width:50%;
    z-index:3000;
 }

 #activityIndicator 
 {
   height: 32px;
   width: 32px;
   -webkit-background-size: 32px 32px;
   -o-background-size: 32px 32px;
   -moz-background-size: 32px 32px;
   background-size: 32px 32px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   background-image: url("activity_indicator.gif");
   background-color: transparent; 
}
```

[image: Activity Indicator - GIF Image]

Comment: That's not a cursor, that's a loading wheel.

Comment: @yashika the Javascript code must be in .js file or can i put it in <script> </script> tags?

Comment: You can put in script tags as well.

Comment: Can you please Inspect Element and let me know, what error do you get?

Comment: I put the Javascript code into <script> tags in the end of the form, before the </form> tag close

Answer (score 4):

Add this attribute to your submit button:

```
onclick="function(){document.body.style.cursor='wait'}"
```

(Apparently in edge, you have to add `void` like `onclick="void function(){document.body...`)

So it should look like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Εκτέλεση ελέγχου" onclick="function(){document.body.style.cursor='wait'}">
```

Now, when you want to reset the cursor, use this code:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
```

Basically,

```
document.body.style.cursor='wait' // loading cursor
```

makes the pointer look like it's loading, and

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'default'; // normal cursor
```

resets it.

Use these in conjunction with your uploading functions, so you could have the button onclick set it to a waiting cursor, and then, when your uploading function has finished, set it back.

Comment: there are 2 problems with this: first, it throws a SyntaxError: function statement requires a name, so you have to do it like this: onclick="(function(){document.body.style.cursor='wait'})()" or onclick="document.body.style.cursor='wait'" and second, it only sets the cursor above BODY, but not when it's above other elements, not even the clicked submit button

Answer (score 0):

While submitting or updating the form, you must be sending some request to server, you can use jquery deferred objects to know the status of request sent, on basis of that status, control showing or hiding of your progress cursor.